# PHP doesn't see mysql extension

Tags: php, mysql

I'm at a loss.  I'm on WIndows 7 and have installed both Apache 2.2.21 and PHP 5.2.17.  I can not enable the mysql module.  Is there a known issue on Windows 7?

I've run php --info and see the following:

```
C:\php>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I've also set my extension dir inside php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
```

I've also added an entry to my httpd.conf file:

```
# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

And yes, inside my php.ini file I've enabled the php_mysql extension and restarted my web server.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you make sure that the MySQL extension is in the extensions folder?

Comment: what does your phpinfo() say ?

Comment: yes I did also verify that...

Comment: Stewie: My phpinfo shows the correct locations etc for my ini file but I don't see the mysql module loaded

Comment: Do you have `extension = mysql.dll` as well? PHP won't auto-load everything in the extension directly, only the .dlls you explicitly list.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Apache/Webserver logs?

Comment: Mark: I do see this: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\php\\ext\\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0.  I've verified that this file exists so I'm at a loss

Comment: *sigh* http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mysql+extension+missing note: if you are a beginner just install wamp.

Comment: yi_H: I've done this many times but never seen anything like this.

Comment: corrupt dll / no permissions?

Comment: @user1216398  add the error to your question

Comment: I was in troubles for almost an hour... then your question gave me the solution.. I was missing # configure the path to php.ini PHPIniDir "c:/php" ... that was enough to solve my bad configuration, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting php_mysql.dll in C:\windows\system32 directory?  If you place the file there, restart your webserver and the module is loaded, then it could mean an environment variable issue, or an old version of php_mysql.dll is preventing the new one from being loaded properly.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried forward slashes here?

```
extension_dir = "C:/php/ext"
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Forward slashes didn't matter on the Win 7 machine I'm working on but giving the full path to the "ext" dir did.

Answer (score 0):

Note to any future information seekers, that mysql extension is deprecated in 5.5 and is gone by PHP 7, to be replaced my the mysqli extension.

Answer (score -1):

Did you install MySQL? I remember I had some kind of that problem because I was expecting PHP to load MySQL extension, before installing MySQL to complete my localhost setup. The reason is when you install MySQL it puts some DLLs to system32 dir so then PHP can load it.

Answer (score -1):

You need php-mysql not just php.
Installing that should take care of adding the right exgtensions to php.

```
yum install php-mysql
```