# PHP doesn't see MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I've already seen this post [PHP doesn't see mysql extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329639/php-doesnt-see-mysql-extension), but it didn't help me.
I use:

- Windows Seven (both 32bit in a VM and 64bit on a real pc)
- Apache 2.2 with SSL
- PHP 5.3.8
- MySql 5.5.23

In `httpd.conf` I configured Apache with PHP

```
PHPIniDir "C:\WEB\PHP\"
LoadModule php5_module "C:\WEB\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll"
ScriptAlias /php "C:/WEB/PHP/"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php-cgi.exe"
```

In `php.ini` I set

```
extension_dir = "C:/WEB/PHP/ext/"
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
[PHP_MYSQLI]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

MySql is started and working, but PHP does not see mysql.
I've also tried to copy `libmysql.dll` into `%windir%\system32` and restarted web server, but it didn't work.
If you need I can post other info.

**UPDATE 1:**
Running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` I can only see `mysqlnd`, but not `mysql` nor `mysqli`.
If I run `php -i` I see

```
mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Apache, PHP and MySQL folders are the same of a previous working pc.
I copied them, reconfigured paths, installed and started services:

```
httpd -k install && httpd -k start
mysqld --install && net start mysql
```

**UPDATE 3:**

- I'm able to use mysql through a DOS console
- If I try to run an existing PhpMyAdmin I get `The mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.`

**UPDATE 4:**
I checked with [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) and the only `php.ini` I have on my pc is the one in php folder.

**UPDATE 5:**
I tried this code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect();
?>
```

and I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\var\www\Apache\test.php on line 4`

Comment: What does phpinfo() say?

Comment: As Starx said, you should phpinfo() out your config. Also, how do you know that php isn't seeing mysql? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Yes it is the problem with paths, then, check if the extensions are present in `C:/web/php/ext/` directory

Comment: Can you connect to the mysql through DOS?

Comment: Are there any PHP errors when you attempt to communicate with mysql?

Comment: Are you certain there are not any duplicate php.ini files laying around? Your mysql block from the phpinfo is similar to mine, so on the outset, looks good.

Comment: Yeah, the default php.ini might show the actual directory, but there might a custom php.ini on your sites root folder as well.

Comment: @MikePurcell: update4. Thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: @Starx: update 4. Thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: I wonder if phpMyAdmin is causing issue, can you write a small script to attempt to connect to MySQL and see if it produces the same error?

Comment: I can't guess anymore. DO a fresh installation of wamp, migrate the database and continue.

Comment: @MikePurcell: update 5... no, same error I think

Comment: According to php.ini documentation, the default extension dir is "ext", which I assume is under the PHP dir, maybe try setting it to just "ext".

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @MikePurcell: yes, finally I managed to solve it: it was a problem in PATH variable not having correct dirs... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most feasible and time saving option I see now, is to do the fresh installation of WAMP itself, and migrate the old files and dbs to the new one.

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed the same problem adding to the Environment Variable "Path" of Windows (System > Advanced > Environment Variables > Path) the following paths:

c:\Program Files\PHP5;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib

The first one is where php.ini is located, the second one (most important!) is where libmysql.dll is located (usually inside the "lib" directory inside the mysql installation dir)

This operations are quite well described in the PHP.net page http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Now it works.

Comment: Thanks, this usually helps. Remember that adding/changing an environemt variable need a pc restart to take effect :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `extension=php_mysql.dll` and `extension=php_mysqli.dll` lines in your php.ini file up. They should be with all the generic settings.

As far as I know, there is no section for `php_mysql` and `php_mysqli`, it's just `mysql` and `mysqli`, but those only contains specific settings for those modules. The actual extensions are loaded before those settings are read.

Comment: `php.ini` has lots of other lines and is the same I used on a previous working pc...

Comment: I would give this a shot, just to remove placement within php.ini as a distractor.