# mysql_query is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM joblist WHERE salary LIKE '%$searchq%' OR jobtitle LIKE '%$searchq%'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0){
    $output = 'There was no search results!';
}else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $salary = $row['$salary'];
        $jobtitle = $row['$jobtitle'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $output .= '<div>' .$salary.' '.$jobtitle.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Fatal error:

```
Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /srv/http/head.php on line 16
```

Comment: I assume line 16 is the first line of the code you posted? Also, the problem is not with the code you posted; had the function mysql_query been defined it would have worked (save unrelated bugs). There's probably a problem in your PHP configuration.

Comment: what should i need to do right now?

Comment: Could you run the following PHP code? `echo phpversion();` If it's 7.0.0 or higher, the mysql_* family of functions is removed (and before it was deprecated). Even if you get the mysql_* functions working you should move to PDO or MySQLi anyway (see the warning [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)).

Comment: Do you have more code that this is just part of? See this article as it will help write a question that allows others to help.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is mysql running on your system ?

Comment: mysql_query() is not supported in newer PHP versions anymore. Please do not use it. Use mysqli_query, or PDO instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mysqli_* if you are using PHP 7. Because mysql_* is not available in this version. Here is the example that you can use it.

```
<?php

// procedural style of mysqli

$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "db";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

if(!$link){
    echo ('unable to connect to database');
}
else {
$sql = "your select query";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
  // SUCCESS STUFF
}
else {
 // error stuff
}
} // end else

?>
```

Comment: @david-sam this is example of mysqli

Comment: @david-sam and most important is that if u think this answer or any other solve yur issue than mark as accept it it will to others who facig same issue... by click on left green tick

Comment: $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password);
$output = ''; what if i use pdo to connect , everything should be pdo as well? if yes, what is the code should be in pdo format?

Answer (score 1):

Mysql_* has been depreciated from PHP 7.0 and onwards. Please use mysqli_*.
Or else downgrade your PHP version to 5.6 or lower. It will work fine.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php( see the waning section of this page).

Answer (score 0):

The PHP extension for mysql is not installed/configured on your system.

Try

- [Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450990/your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql-extension-which-is-require) to ensure the module is actually enabled
- Install on Linux Ubuntu http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-mysql-php-support-for-wordpress/
- Windows [PHP doesn't see mysql extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329639/php-doesnt-see-mysql-extension)

This being said, you should use *mysqli* (not *mysql*) extension, as *mysql* is deprecated, not recommended and will be out of PHP7.